# Waiting for multiple asynchronous JSON queries to finish before running code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous, callback

I am looking to run multiple different JSON request simultaneously, and then only perform a function once they have either completed or returned an error message (404 etc.). Here's what I have so far, but the function `finished` doesn't remember the variables from either request. Any ideas?

```
function socialPosting(a_date,a_title,a_source,a_thumbnail,a_url) {
        socialPosts[socialPosts.length] = {date: a_date, title: a_title, source: a_source, thumbnail: a_thumbnail, url: a_url};
        //console.log(socialPosts[amount]);
        //console.log(amount);
    }

function finished(source) {
        if (source == "Twitter") {
            var Twitter = "True";
        }
        if (source == "YouTube") {
            var YouTube = "True";
        }
        console.log(source); //diagnostics
        console.log(Twitter); //diagnostics
        console.log(YouTube); //diagnostics
        if (Twitter == "True" && YouTube == "True") { 
            console.log(socialPosts[0]); //Should return after both requests are complete
        }
    }

$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=google&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published', function(data) {
        for(var i=0; i<data.data.items.length; i++) { //for each YouTube video in the request
            socialPosting(Date.parse(data.data.items[i].uploaded),data.data.items[i].title,"YouTube",data.data.items[i].thumbnail.hqDefault,'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + data.data.items[i].id); //Add values of YouTube video to array
        }
        finished("YouTube");
    });

$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/twitter.json?count=5&include_rts=1&callback=?", function(data) {
        var amount = socialPosts.length;
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            socialPosting(Date.parse(data[i].created_at),data[i].text,"Twitter"); //Add values of YouTube video to array
        }
        finished("Twitter");
    });
```

Comment: This is what promises are for.

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate as the solution here is closer to what I had in the question than the duplicate.

Comment: Sure, but the *overall problem* is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, in your solution Twitter and Youtube are local variables in the function finished, after the function returns they no longer exist, if the function gets called again they are craeted again but of course they don´t have the value of last time since they are new variables, maybe google for 'javascript variable scope' for more information about this topic.

```
var Twitter = false;
var YouTube = false;
function finished(source) {
    if (source == "Twitter") {
        Twitter = true;
    }
    if (source == "YouTube") {
        YouTube = true;
    }
    console.log(source);
    console.log(Twitter);
    console.log(YouTube);
    if (Twitter && YouTube) { 
        console.log(socialPosts[0]);
    }
}
```

Also add an error handler to your json-request via 
`$.getJSON(...).fail(function () {console.log('error');});`

Comment: It boggles my mind why that worked. I was going to add that later but didn't realise there was any difference between undefined and true when checking if they are true. Thankyou

Comment: The key change is moving the variable declaration out of the function, not making it in the function.
changing their value from string to booleans wasn´t necessary for this, but i couldn´t look at the code with that it in ;)

Comment: Yeah I originally had it as (what I thought was boolean), but it gave me errors. Turned out I was using True instead of true.

Comment: What if one request fail?! Your finished function won't be called from this request success callback

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, i added more code ;)